# GeoPandas geocode error when using Nominatim

Tags: python, geocoding, geopandas, nominatim, attributeerror

I am following [this lesson about Geocoding](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/lessons/L3/geocoding.html).

I have entered:

```
# Import necessary modules
import pandas as pd

# Filepath
fp = r"addresses.txt"

# Read the data
data = pd.read_csv(fp, sep=';')
data.head()

#geocoding tool
from geopandas.tools import geocode

#nominatim
geo = geocode(data['addr'], provider='nominatim')
geo.head(2)
```

but get this error:

> AttributeError: module `'geopy.geocoders'` has no attribute `'Yahoo'`

What is the problem here?

Also, I have an API key for Nominatim, where would I put that? I defined the key:

`key = "#########################"`

then tried:

`geo = geocode(data['addr'], provider='nominatim', key = key)`

and

`geo = geocode(data['addr'], provider='nominatim', **kwargs = key)`

and they didn't work. I have tried to look for solutions online, but they were unclear about how to use the API key.

Comment: Look similar as this issue [Geocoding error with geopandas and geopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132636/geocoding-error-with-geopandas-and-geopy?rq=1).

Comment: Can you try installing GeoPandas from master and see if that solves your problem?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I don't know what you mean by installing GeoPandas from master though. Can you explain that? Do you know what I should do with the API as well?

Comment: I also tried the solution that you posted and that didn't solve my issue.